# Does the Upgrade Tool in Kubuntu Erase Current Programs & Configurations?

Tags: upgrade, 17.04, 17.10

I'm interested in upgrading to Kubuntu 17.10, but I'm not certain if the upgrade tool will erase my current programs & configurations. I mean, I would kind of expect this behavior from upgrading and I maintain good backups, I'm just curious.

Answer (score 0):

I completed the upgrade. Data integrity is ok, programs are ok, previous desktop settings/configurations are ok. I have run into some issues with USB drivers (I expected such, you should too), but graphics drivers are fine. Wayland is ok as a desktop server as well, no weird issues on my hardware. If you are going to attempt the upgrade, ensure that you use a backup tool such as GNOME Backups (My preferred) beforehand.